# Google Meet Link is not generating

Tags: reactjs, google-calendar-api, google-meet

i have integrated Gcalender to my app and the event is created but in that event the Gmeet link is not created i have read the documentation written in Developers.google but not working can anyone Suggest a change in my code I am posting my code here:

```
const Calender = () => {
    var gapi = window.gapi
    var CLIENT_ID = "*********"
    var API_KEY = "*******"
    var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"]
    var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"
  
    const handleClick = () => {
      gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
        console.log('loaded client')
  
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES,
        })
  
        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', () => console.log('bam!'))
  
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
        .then(() => {
          
          var event = {
            'summary': 'Awesome Event!',
            'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
            'description': 'Really great refreshments',
            'start': {
              'dateTime': '2020-06-28T09:00:00-07:00',
              'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata'
            },
            'end': {
              'dateTime': '2020-06-28T17:00:00-07:00',
              'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata'
            },
            'conferenceData': {
              'createRequest': {
                  'requestId': 'sample123',
                  'conferenceSolutionKey': {'type': 'hangoutsMeet'},
                  'status': {'statusCode': 'success'}
              }
          },
            'recurrence': [
              'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
            ],
            'attendees': [
              {'email': 'ananthapadmanabhan7025@example.com'},
              {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'}
            ],
            'reminders': {
              'useDefault': false,
              'overrides': [
                {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
                {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
              ]
            }
          }
  
          var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
            'calendarId': 'primary',
            'resource': event
          });
          request.conferenceDataVersion = 1;
          request.execute(event => {
            console.log(event)
            window.open(event.htmlLink)
          })
          
  
         
          
          gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
            'calendarId': 'primary',
            'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
            'showDeleted': false,
            'singleEvents': true,
            'maxResults': 10,
            'orderBy': 'startTime'
          }).then(response => {
            const events = response.result.items
            console.log('EVENTS: ', events)
          })
        
      
  
        })
      })
    }
  
  
    return (
      <>
      <button  onClick={handleClick}>Add Event</button></>
    );
  }
  
  export default Calender;
```

i have put gapi script in my index.html file also

Answer (score 1):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
  'calendarId': 'primary',
  'resource': event
});
```

#### To

```
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
  'calendarId': 'primary',
  'resource': event,
  'conferenceDataVersion': 1, // Added
});
```

#### Reference:

- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)